# How to implement updating realm object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have subclass from RLMRealm named User.

```
@interface User : RLMRealm

// Default Properties, using for show user in lists.
@property NSString *uID;
@property NSString *nickname;
@property NSString *imageURL;

// User Details Properties, using when opening user profile
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *secondName;
@property NSDate  *birthday;
@property NSInteger followersCount;
@property NSInteger followingsCount;
@property (getter = isFollowed) BOOL followed;
@property (getter = isAllowedToFollow) BOOL allowedToFollow;

@end
```

When I get a list of users with the Default Properties, I keep them in the the Realm, then when I open User profile, I get the same User with Details Properties and update that user in Realm. But then again, when I get the user from the list, and renew again, I lose Details Properties. 
What can I do to not lose the Details Properties? Thanks.

Comment: That's odd. That sounds like it should be working fine. Can you please post your code that deals with saving the data? Realm doesn't actually load items into memory until you actually call them, so you don't need to worry about breaking up your properties into 'default' and 'detailed' categories. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to update the user without details it would overwrite the existing information.

I would say try to repopulate the details before you update the record.